# How to add icons to menu items in c++ win32 API

Tags: c++, api, winapi, menu, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [InsertMenu/AppendMenu - How to add Icons to menu and submenus using C++ and win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181063/insertmenu-appendmenu-how-to-add-icons-to-menu-and-submenus-using-c-and-win3)

Hello I have a menu in c++ here is the code of it

```
HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
HMENU hFileMenu = CreatePopupMenu;
HMENU HFileOpen = CreateMenu;

AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, (UINT)hFileOpen, "Open");
AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hFileMenu, "File");

SetMenu(hwnd,hMenu);
```

I have been looking all over the internet and I can't seen to find a tutorial on how to make bitmaps for the menu item.
I want to add a bitmap for hFileOpen.
How would I do it?

Comment: Unless MS added the feature and I totally missed it icons on menu items were/are strictly owner-draw. I.e. you have to draw the menu item yourself. Been awhile since I did it so that may have changed.

Comment: You could use the functions instead of it being a resource. Just start off with a `CreateMenu` and use [`AppendMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647616(v=vs.85).aspx) to add onto it.

Comment: Well look at that. They did add it. Been a long time. SetMenuItemBitmaps ftw (among other ways).

Comment: Specify the `hbmpItem` field of `MENUITEMINFO`. On Vista and up you can use a PARGB32 bitmap to get alpha blended glyphs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [InsertMenu/AppendMenu - How to add Icons to menu and submenus using C++ and win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181063/insertmenu-appendmenu-how-to-add-icons-to-menu-and-submenus-using-c-and-win3) or [C++: Step 1: ExtractIconEx. Step 2: ??? Step 3: SetMenuItemBitmaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96414/c-step-1-extracticonex-step-2-step-3-setmenuitembitmaps)

Answer (score 2):

SetMenuItemInfo
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Im not exactly sure how to use that function maybe you can help me out

Comment: @ArtursLapins See MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Using_Menu_Item_Bitmaps

Answer (score 2):

First you shall load the bitmap from resource. You can use [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LoadBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API functions to load bitmap.

It will return a new image handle.
Then you can use this handle to assign bitmap to menu item via [SetMenuItemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

See also MSDN topic about [using bitmaps with menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Using_Menu_Item_Bitmaps) that describes it step by step.

Comment: Can you help me, I'm not sure how to use it Microsoft dosen't explain well.

Comment: Well the function will look something like this: 

`// create a bitmap`
`HBITMAP bitmap;`

`// Load the bitmap resource`
`bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage( HINSTANCE, "file.type", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);`

After that create a MENUITEMINFO and send it by pointer to the 
SetMenuItemInfo function.

Comment: sorry im a little confuzed is HINSTANCE, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0,0 and LR_LOADFROMFILE supposto stay the same or i have to change them, if i do which one and to what

Comment: The hinstance has to change to whatever your HINSTANCE is. You get that value from winmain. The other values stay the same. IMAGE_BITMAP is used to specify that this is a bitmap file. the two 0's implies that we will load the image using whatever the actual image size is. And LR_LOADFROMFILE tells windows to actually load this resource from the file on disk.

Comment: okay this is what i have:
'HBITMAP bitmap;'
'bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, "menuicons/fileopen.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);' now how do i tell my AppendMenu to add that bitmap?

Comment: Rost modified my post to include a link to a tutorial on MSDN that carefully elaborates every step of the process. Here it is again. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Using_Menu_Item_Bitmaps)